# Vimeo video duration fetch doesn't work php

Tags: php, wordpress, vimeo-api

I'm trying to fetch the vimeo video duration from the video url in localhost wordpress website but getting the resource not found error with the error message shown below:

```
{"error":"Something strange occurred. Please try again.","link":null,"developer_message":"The specified resource doesn't exist.","error_code":5000}
```

I've tried answers that are already available but that didn't help.

Code I tired:

```
if (isset($videoUrl)) {
    $getHost = parse_url($videoUrl);
    if($getHost['host'] == 'vimeo.com') {
    $regs = array();
    $id = '';
    if (preg_match('%^https?:\/\/(?:www\.|player\.)?vimeo.com\/(?:channels\/(?:\w+\/)? 
    |groups\/([^\/]*)\/videos\/|album\/(\d+)\/video\/|video\/|)(\d+)(?:$|\/|\?)(?:[?]?.*)$%im', 
    $videoUrl, $regs)) {
       $id = $regs[3];
    }
    $authorization = 'key';
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/$id?field=duration",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer {$authorization}",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    if (empty($err)) {
        info = json_decode($response);
        if(isset($info->duration)){
            return (int)$info->duration;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Secondly does the authorization key works for all vimeo videos or for the video of the account to which it is associated ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you do any debugging to see where the error was happening? For example, is the value in `$id` correct, or is it invalid and resulting in the "The specified resource doesn't exist" message?

Comment: yeah everything is fine I think the problem is with the video url scheme. I''ve url of this sort  `https://vimeo.com/913337225/1066adfeb6` for which I couldn't find any scheme in the docs.